# How to use WebSockets with react and Nestjs?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I want to use websockets for a react app and nestjs backend with socket.io and socket.io-client.

But i can't establish the communication via websockets between frontend and backend.

here my frontend page using websockets:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const ENDPOINT = "ws://localhost:3000/";

const socket = io(ENDPOINT).connect();

const Room = () => {
    
    const location = useLocation<{roomId: string}>()
    const roomId = location.state.roomId
    const [gameStart, setGameStart] = useState(false);
    const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("gameStarted", () => {
            setGameStart(true)
        })
        socket.on('joinedRoom', () => {
            console.log('room joined');
        })
    }, [socket])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit('joinRoom', {name: 'username', roomId: roomId})

    }, [socket])
    
    const launchGame = () => {
        console.log(roomId);
        socket.emit('startGame', {roomId: roomId})
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>Room</div>
            <Button onClick={() => {launchGame()}}variant="success">Start the GAME</Button>
            {gameStart ? <p>truc</p> : <p>chose</p>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Room
```

and here my nest gateway:

```js
import { ConnectedSocket, MessageBody, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayInit, SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer } from "@nestjs/websockets";
import { Socket, Server } from 'socket.io'
import { RoomService } from "./room.service";
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid'

@WebSocketGateway()
export class RoomGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection {

    parties: Array<string>
    
    public constructor (private roomService: RoomService) {
    }

    @WebSocketServer()
    server: Server;

    afterInit(server: any) {
        console.log(server);
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('chatToServer')
    handleMessage(client: Socket, data: { sender: string, room: string, message: string}): void {
       this.server.to(data.room).emit('chatToClient', data.message);
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('createRoom')
    handleCreateRoom(client: Socket): void {
       const id = uuidv1();
        client.join(id);
        client.emit('roomCreated', { room: id });
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('startGame')
    handleStartGame(client: Socket, roomId: string): void {
        console.log('aodzjoiajdzoi')
        this.roomService.startGame(6);
        this.server.to(roomId).emit('gameStarted');
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('movePawn')
    handleMovePawn(client: Socket,
    data: { sender: string, roomId: string,
    movement: { oldX: number, oldY: number, newX: number, newY: number } }): void {
        if (this.roomService.movePawn(data.movement)) {
            this.server.to(data.roomId).emit('movePawn', data)
        } else {
            client.emit('impossibleMove')
        }
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('joinRoom')
    handleJoinRoom(
        @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket,
        @MessageBody() data: {name: string, roomId: string}): void {
        console.log('room joined');
        client.join(data.roomId)
        client.emit('joinedRoom', data.roomId);
        this.server.to(data.roomId).emit('newPlayer', data.name);
    }

    handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
        //console.log('client connected')
    }
```

So my console.log in the joinRoom doesn't work when I made an emit on it. I think my client isn't connected but i don't know why.